# How to route traffic from 2 NIC's on the same PC and more about configuring a switch?

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, nat

[image]

Hey everyone! I hope you guys can help me with a problem I have been struggling with. So, the image describes a network architecture. The PC is running Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.

1. Port 1 and 2 = Public facing ports with public IP (Internet connectivity).
2. Port 3 and 4 = Private ports with no internet connectivity.
3. Port 3 has a DHCP server running on it (isc-dhcp-server).
4. Port 3 has a self assigned IP address using the command "sudo ifconfig eth3 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0".
5. Port 3 is connected to VLAN1 on the switch. We can ignore the AP for simplicity.

Questions -

1. Whatever traffic is coming in through port 1 has to be redirected to port 3 and vica versa. I know this has to do with IP forwarding, Routing Tables and NAT Tables but I have not been able to figure this out. I have enabled IP Forwarding. Basically any device that gets connected to the AP on VLAN1 has to obtain an IP address from the DHCP server and get internet connectivity using Port 1.
2. When I connect a PC to any port on VLAN1, it gets a random address and is not from the DHCP server. Also, I cannot ping the port 3 from the pc. So, I am sure I am missing something. Kindly help me out.

Comment: You write, "When I connect a PC to any port on VLAN1", is that a different system than the one labled "PC" in your diagram? What is the address from "it gets a random address"?  Is it something like 169.254.x.y?  Has your DHCP server ever successfully issued an IP address on VLAN1?  The outputs from the following commands may be helpful: "ip addr show", "ip route show", "cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward", although your setup may be many steps away from routing, and you might need to start with a question about the DHCP.

Comment: Hi there. Try two things at first: 1) use a static address in the range of Port 3 on a host X in VLAN 1 and ping the PC Port 3. If it works, the VLAN setup is ok. 2) Start on PC:  `sudo tcpdump -v -s0 -X -i eth3`, then activate host X and start a  `ping  X` from another terminal on PC. Paste the output here, so we can see how DHCP behaves.

Comment: Are VLANs just isolated nets, or really using VLAN IDs as in 802.1Q? In such case, depending on settings, tagged frames have to be used, or not. Also traditionally VLAN ID 1 is used for management VLAN unless changed. I'd add the `-e` option to gerhard d.'s tcpdump command so VLAN information if any is also displayed. Also since nothing is told about the interface 4 (eth4?), if nothing special is done there it could currently be ignored, and should and no special policy routing should be needed. Even better: it should be disconnected during troubleshooting.